# Can a Ring of Force Shield be activated and deactivated multiple times in the same round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, actions

I am a little unclear about the rules covering  *ring of force shield* with archery.

Can the ring be activated and deactivated multiple times in the same round?

Is the following possible with a 10th-level ranger?

1. turn off ring as free action
2. quick draw bow
3. cast instant enemy as swift action
4. full attack with archery
5. turn ring back on as free action

Is that possible, within the rules?

Comment: Can this question link to the developers' intent with regard to the *ring of force shield*? Further, I'm unsure of the question: It sounds like you understand how the *ring* interacts with archery and *just don't like it*, in which case you should make a house rule for your campaigns… but that isn't a question. Sincerely, what can the site help you with?

Comment: I am not sure  how the ring is supposed to work with archery. I seen campaigns where it is ruled you can use with archery and i seen campaigns where you can not use it with archery.  It all pretty much came down to can turn it on and off in same round.  I just want to know if there was any offical statement about this

Comment: The [*ring*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-force-shield/)'s description says, "It can be activated and deactivated at will as a free action." That's insufficient? Is this a question then about free actions and the GM's ability to limit them arbitrarily? How long ago did you hear about the campaigns in which this was disallowed? Can you link to any discussions? (There was a limited-number-of-free-actions-controversy briefly, like, five years ago I think, but that's long since resolved.)

Comment: I am primary asking can you turn an item on and off in the same round.  I am aware of campaigns that were run the past year or so where it was not allowed. I am in a campaign right now where the DM has to decide to allow it or not.  Both i and the DM have playing pathfinder for little more then a year and we watch people run campaigns at a comic book store

Comment: I'm not sure the site can help. I mean, the *ring* description says what it says.  *By default* the *ring* can be "activated and deactivated at will as a free action"! It sounds like it would be up to the *no* side to prove its case and not up to the *yes* side to prove the *no* side wrong! Further, it sounds like the item description is just *not enough* and that you'd prefer a developer to chime in, but unless the developers have commented on this item specifically, the site has no way to *create* that information—it's just luck if it's already happened. That said…

Comment: …If you want to edit the question so as to simplify it to something like, "Can a *ring of force shield* be activated and deactivated multiple times during the wearer's turn?" I'll vote to take the question off hold. However, I won't make such a vote while the question is, essentially, "Has a developer confirmed that the *ring of force shield* can be activated and deactivated multiple times during the wearer's turn?"

Comment: So the GM decided that getting +2 shield bonus to AC at the cost of 8k gold and one of the two precious ring slots is too powerful? Has he heard of [Rings of Protection](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-protection/)?

Answer (score 1):

## That chain of events looks legit

The description of the ***ring of force shield***, in part, says, "It can be activated and deactivated at will as a free action." The *ring* puts no limit on the number of times the wearer can take a free activation to activate it, deactivate it, and activate it again.

A GM can make a house rule to change how the *ring* works if it annoys him, but, by default, this is how the *ring* works. Further, while the GM can impose an arbitrary limit on the number of free actions a creature can take during its turn (see [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Free-Actions)), unless the GM *does* impose such a limit on the [*ring of force shield*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-force-shield/), the *ring* can be used until the wearer gets bored with turning it off and on.

---

***Note:*** This answer assumes all of the links in the chain of events involve typical arrangements of appropriate game elements. The chain of events falls apart if the bow is stored in a securely-locked chest rather than jauntily and heroically—if unrealistically—slung over one's shoulder, for instance.